# About weak* density of $X$ in $X^{**}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

I know for a Banach space $X$, $X$ is weak$^*$ dense in $X^{**}$(double dual of $X$).
However, I'm not clear that for $x^{**}\in X^{**}, y_1, y_2\in X^*$ and given $a_1, a_2\in\mathbb{R}$, there is $x\in X$ such that
$|(x^{**}-x)(y_1)|<a_1$ and $|(x^{**}-x)(y_2)|<a_2$ simultaneously.

I think this is related to the question whether a weak-star neighborhood $\{x^*\in X^* : x^*(x_1)<\epsilon_1, x^*(x_2)<\epsilon_2 \}\neq\varnothing$ or not. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $x^{**} \in X^{**}$ then there is a net $\{ x_i \}_{I \in I} \subset X = \text{dual of} ~(X^* , w^*)$

Such that $x_i \overset{w^*}{\rightarrow} x^{**}$. The later convergence coincides with pointwise convergence on $X^*$

Comment: Oh, I got it thank you '';;;